# Route login not defined (Multi-auth)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-passport

I have problem with multi-auth. Postman says error:

problem:

> > Route [login] not defined.

I understand it doesn't know which one to route?

I try to make laravel passport api so I dont need any automatic redirections.. I try to create multi-auth.

Like Admins, Stylists, Freelancers, clients..

Every route have own login and registration and other routes..

I tryed to ungroup but this isn't good solution..

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['json.response']], function () {

    Route::get('/freelancer/{profile}', 'API\FreelancerController@profile'); // Guests can also see profiles..

    Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin', 'namespace' => 'API', 'middleware' => 'auth:admin'], function() {
        Route::post('/login', 'AdminController@login');
    });
    Route::group(['prefix' => 'freelancer', 'namespace' => 'API', 'middleware' => 'auth:freelancer'], function() {
        Route::post('/login', 'LoginRegisterController@login');
        Route::post('/register', 'LoginRegisterController@freelancerRegister');
    });

    Route::group(['prefix' => 'stylist', 'namespace' => 'API', 'middleware' => 'auth:stylist'], function() {
        Route::post('/login', 'LoginRegisterController@login');
        Route::post('/register', 'LoginRegisterController@stylistRegister');
    });

    Route::group(['prefix' => 'client', 'namespace' => 'API', 'middleware' => 'auth:client'], function() {
        Route::post('/login', 'ClientController@login');
        Route::post('/register', 'ClientController@clientRegister');
    });
});
```

If I'm http://api.mywebsite.com/freelancer/register then I can register freelancer account..

Or If I'm http://api.mywebsite.com/admin/login then I can only login to admin dashboard.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve is not clear,

Comment: in your login form check `action="{{}}"` cause in your route file there is no login route ?

Answer (score 0):

#### POSSIBILITY 1

Please check what route you are targetting when creating a login request from POSTMAN.

I believe you are using a route like
 `http://api.mywebsite.com/login`

whereas you should be using one of the following:

- http://api.mywebsite.com/admin/login
- http://api.mywebsite.com/freelancer/login
- http://api.mywebsite.com/stylist/login
- http://api.mywebsite.com/client/login

#### POSSIBILITY 2

If above isn't the case and you are targetting a good route then check your method, it should be `POST`, by default POSTMAN uses `GET` method when you initialize a request.

However, chances for this mistake is less as it would give rather `METHOD NOT EXIST` error than `ROUTE NOT FOUND` but it's worth a try.

Comment: I use http://api.mywebsite.com/freelancer/register
Image of Postman: https://imgur.com/Xeq4AZs I think problem is with that file: https://imgur.com/M5Fj2H2

Comment: Found issue! Problem is `middleware => 'auth:freelancer'` and in  that group was login and register controllers. it must be outside of auth checking.. Thats why need to take breaks of coding sometimes :/

Comment: Glad you solved it, you should post it as an answer and accept it to close this thread